# How to set Autolayout constraint for Video Player

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am playing video in view controller, and I want to set top space, leading space, trailing space of video player. How can I set this using autolayout programatically ?

Here is my code which displays Movie Player.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[WebArray objectForKey:@"video_url"]]];
                AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayerLayer layer];
[layer setPlayer:player];
[layer setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 86, 280, 160)];
[layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor].CGColor];
[layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:layer];
[player play];
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance !!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(5)-[layer(==20)]-(5)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(layer)]];

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(5)-[layer(==20)]-(0)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(layer)]];
```

here 5 is leading, top, trailling space, and 20 is height and width

Edit 1:
First add AVPlayer to a new UIView and then add constraints to that view

```
UIView *myview = [UIView alloc] init];
[myview.layer addSublayer:layer];
```

Comment: In first line metrics:metrics gives me error that metrics is undefined. Please clarify it.

Comment: Yes. I had checked, but it gives me an error

-----Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings failed because either one of the values is nil, or there's something wrong with the way the macro is being invoked.  Cannot assign value nil for key "player". Keys:(player ----

Comment: change player to layer

Comment: where to change ? I am not able to write views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(layer) .

Comment: It gives me an error that --- use of undeclared layer ---

Comment: ...........
[layer setVideoGravity:AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill];

 UIView *myview = [[UIView alloc] init];
  [myview.layer addSublayer:layer];
                [player play];
                
 [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(5)-[layer(==20)]-(5)-|" options:NSLayoutFormatDirectionLeadingToTrailing metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(layer)]];
..........
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AVPlayerLayer nsli_superitem]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fd918ec5360'

Comment: myview in constraints not layer

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. Still thanks for your help.